# handling server error(500) in (django) web app

Tags: ajax, django, error-handling

I have written a web app that uses `ajax` and  `django` .It parses a file ,collects some data from the file ,and then presents the user with results of processing the data.

If the file was not in the expected format,the parsing and data processing would fail and the program would tell the user that the  file could not be processed.

I tried this way

```
def process_file(request):
    success = False
    return_dict = {}    
    ...
    if (request.is_ajax()) and(request.method == "POST"):
        filename = request.POST['filename']
        ...
        data = parse_file(filename)
        results = process_data(data)
        success = True
        return_dict = {'result':results}
     serialized = json.dumps(return_dict)
     if success == True:
         return HttpResponse(serialized,mimetype="application/json")
     else:
        return HttpResponseServerError(serialized, mimetype="application/json")
```

In `javascript`,I have a function which checks status of `ajax query` .If `status is not 'success'` ,it displays an error message.

This works even if there is a 500 error in django view, when I am using the django server.The server console shows 500 error but still goes on without a hitch. I am wondering if this would be the case if it is deployed in production environment.

Is there a better way to handle the runtime errors in django view ? What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not truly responding to errors. As long as the request was sent as a POST via AJAX, `success` is *always* `True`. This tells you nothing about whether the file could be parsed, or heck, even if a file was uploaded *at all*.

First and foremost, you code will currently *always* fail (500 error) because there's no `request.post`; it should be `request.POST`.

Second, any time you need to pull a value out of `request.POST`, you should always you `dict.get`, i.e.:

```
filename = request.POST.get('filename')
```

If the field is not found in the POST data, `filename` will equal `None`. You should therefore, branch on this, only going on with the rest of the code if `filename` is not `None`, e.g.:

```
if filename is None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
else:
    # the rest of your code
```

Third, I'm assuming `filename` is an input with `type="file"`. If that's the case, it won't actually exist in `request.POST`, anyways. All file uploads go into `request.FILES`. The same notes above apply:

```
filename = request.FILES.get('filename')
if filename is None:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
else:
    # the rest of your code
```

Fourth, both `parse_file` and `process_data` seem to be proprietary methods you created, so it's not possible to give you much help there. But remember to judiciously use `try...except` blocks whenever you're doing anything that could fail, such as reading data from a file, or parsing that data in an assumed format that it's not actually in.

Your `parse_file` and `process_data` methods should catch *all* possible exceptions. Then they can either propagate them upward, raise another custom exception in their place, or simply fail silently returning something like `None`. It's then up to your view here to respond accordingly, catching the exception or branching on whether the returned value is `None` or not.